# Estimation of an expression in Evans PDE

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $\epsilon(t)=\frac{A}{t^{1/2}}, t>0$, $A$ is a large positive number. How to prove that $$\left(\left(1+\epsilon\right)t\right)^{1/2}-t^{1/2}=O(1)?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe we have
\begin{align}
((1+\epsilon)t)^{1/2}-t^{1/2} = \frac{\epsilon t}{((1+\epsilon)t)^{1/2}+t^{1/2}} = \frac{At^{1/2}}{(t+At^{1/2})^{1/2}+t^{1/2}}.
\end{align}
Next, we have
\begin{align}
0 \leq \frac{A}{2+A^{1/2}/t^{1/4}}=\frac{At^{1/2}}{2t^{1/2}+A^{1/2}t^{1/4}}\leq \frac{At^{1/2}}{(t+At^{1/2})^{1/2}+t^{1/2}} \leq A
\end{align}